# Error importing hand-written theme pack in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, themes

I created a theme pack by hand and when importing, Windows told me

> Windows can't save this theme to your computer

Here's the theme file I've written, according to [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773190(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
[Theme]
; Windows - IDS_THEME_DISPLAYNAME_AERO
DisplayName=TestTheme
ThemeId={1285AB36-C1B6-4207-A43E-84FCE21B54E4} ; Randomly typed

[Control Panel\Desktop]
Wallpaper=Images\default.jpg
Pattern=
MultimonBackgrounds=0
PicturePosition=4
WallpaperStyle=10

[Slideshow]
Interval=600000
Shuffle=1
ImagesRootPath=Images

[VisualStyles]
Path=%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\Aero.msstyles
ColorStyle=NormalColor
Size=NormalSize
AutoColorization=1
ColorizationColor=0XC44D71B3
VisualStyleVersion=10
Transparency=1

[MasterThemeSelector]
MTSM=DABJDKT
```

And as well, Here's the directory tree of my working folder:

```
MyTheme\
  MyTheme.theme
  Images\
    default.jpg
    image1.jpg
    image2.jpg
```

I've successfully packed the theme into a CAB and renamed it to `MyTheme.deskthemepack`, and it gone all through until I double-click in Explorer, when Windows gave me the error above.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Background: I'm going to write a script to automatically generate theme packs from my photo library, so I decided to create the first one by hand to clear out any potential problems with the theme pack itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very strange, but `DesktopBackground` seems to be the only valid name for the folder containing background images.

Changing all `Images` in the theme file and renaming the folder to `DesktopBackground` worked for me. Additionally, I tried a few similar names and they all failed.